# Django extra context item in HttpResponse

Tags: python, django

I have my view defined as follow:

```
class HomeView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "home.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(HomeView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['items'] = Item.objects.all()
        return context

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        #Getting data from an api call here
        response = api.get_some_items()
        list_with_items = []
        for i, item in enumerate(response):
            list_with_items.append(item.name)

        template = loader.get_template('home.html')
        context = self.get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['extra_items'] = list_with_items

        return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

In the template I loop through the list as follow, but it does not seem to render anything from that context, which I know because I put the `{% empty %}` tag in there.

```
{% for item in items %}
    {{ item }}
{% empty %}
    <p>No items</p>
{% endfor %}
```

What does go wrong here?

EDIT: When I put a trace right before the HttpResponse, `context['extra_items']`returned all the items in the list, but does not render it to the template

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are messing up with Class based views. Why would you use `TemplateView` for this?

You may try something like this instead:

```
from django.views.generic.list import ListView


class HomeView(ListView):
    model = Item
    context_object_name = 'items'
    template_name = "home.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(HomeView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        response = api.get_some_items()
        list_with_items = []
        for i, item in enumerate(response):
            list_with_items.append(item.name)
        context['extra_items'] = list_with_items
        return context
```